# Index File on GoDaddy is not displaying any PHP works perfect in local XAMPP

Tags: php

The below code works perfect on my local server using XAMPP.  When uploaded to GoDaddy, none of the PHP works and I get this line repeated twice.

--> Get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career!

--> get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career!

**This is what should be displayed**

"Good evening, today is Tuesday. The time is now 22:47. Jaza Solutions is now closed. We will be open again at 8 AM tomorrow. Please give us a call tomorrow and get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career!"

The technicians on GoDaddy suggested I google the problem.  I'm lost on how this works locally but not over their servers.  Any help is very much appreciated!

```
<?php
    $day = date('l'); 
    $time = date('H:i');
    $hour = date('H');
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Project Management Training and Consulting">
        <meta name="keywords" content="PMP, CAPM, Agile, ITIL, PMI-ACP, SCRUM, Waldorf, MD, Washington, DC, Alexandria, VA">
        <meta name="author" content="Vince McKeown">
        <title>Jaza Solutions - Home</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet"
        type = "text/css"
        href = "jazasolutions.css" /> 
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.mil.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript"
        src = "navmenu.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <img src="jazasolutions2.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
        </div>
        <nav>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>        
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsContact.html>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsAboutUs.html>About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsCourses.html>Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <img class="imageSideRight" src="Meeting.jpeg" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
        </div>
        <div class="sideRight">
            <h2> Upcoming Classes </h2>
            <p class="microsoft marquee"><span>Enrollment discounted at 50% for a limited time for the <font color="red">6/25/18</font color> PMP boot camp.</span></p>
            <p> <font color="red">6/25/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p> 
            <p> <font color="red">7/23/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "main">
            <?php if ($hour > 0 && $hour < 8) { ?>
            <p> Good morning, today is <?php echo $day; ?>.  The time is now <?php echo $time; ?>. Jaza Solutions will be open at 8 AM.  Please give us a call shortly and 
            <?php } elseif ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 12) { ?>
            <p> Good morning, today is <?php echo $day; ?>.  The time is now <?php echo $time; ?>.  Jaza Solutions is open.  Please give us a call at (301)861-2133 and 
            <?php } elseif ($hour >= 12 && $hour < 17) { ?>
            <p> Good afternoon, today is <?php echo $day; ?>.  The time is now <?php echo $time; ?>. Jaza Solutions is open.  The time is now <?php echo $time; ?>.  Jaza Solutions is open.  Please give us a call at (301)861-2133 and
            <?php } else { ?>

            <p> Good evening, today is <?php echo $day; ?>. The time is now <?php echo $time; ?>. Jaza Solutions is now closed.  We will be open again at 8 AM tomorrow.  Please give us a call tomorrow and get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career! <?php } ?>     </p>
            <br>
            <h1> Jaza Solutions offers industry endorsed training in: </h1>
            <ol> 
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsPMP.html>PMP</li><p><i>New Knowledge area sample questions now available</i></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsCAPM.html>CAPM</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsITIL.html>ITIL</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsAgile.html>Agile & Scrum</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsSixSigma.html>Six Sigma</a></li>
            </ol>
            <br>
            <h1> The Jaza Advantage: </h1>
            <ul> 
                <li> Acquire certifications in Management not just training </li>
                <li> Get trained by experts at your site or ours </li>
                <li> Flexible training hours & online training to fit your needs </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "footer">
            <img class="imageSideRight" src="PMI.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC" height="60" margin-bottom= "0px" width = "100">
            <p>  <br> Call us:  (301)861-2133 <br> Email us: info@jazasolutions.com <br><small>&copy; 2017 Jaza Solutions, LLC</small></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: website is www.jazasolutions.com

Comment: Have you, or Godaddy techs, confirmed you've got php running on your server at all?

http://www.htmlite.com/php003.php

Comment: Hi Ryan.  I didn't do the step you suggested, but I did try with a different file to ensure PHP is working on their server.  I'll try that code now and see what I get.

Comment: www.jazasolutions.com/index.php see the difference?

Comment: Just checked your site, the PHP is working fine. The symptoms you're seeing are caused by the javascript magic you have going on, which is replacing the "Good evening" text with a second "Get the Management Certification" text.

Comment: Wow, it works when adding index.php!  Shouldn't the site navigate there when just typing in www.jazasolutions.com?

Comment: @rickdenhaan, confirmed. It looks like the text is in the markup but not displayed.

Comment: I've deleted the index.html file prior to uploading the index.php file.

Comment: Your jquery CDN is wrong.. should be (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Corrected the jquery to above.

Comment: I've deleted all the javascript.  I don't see the double lines any more, which is a positive, but it still doesn't display the PHP data of the date.  The correct file still shows if I type in www.jazasolutions.com/index.php, but not www.jazasolutions.com.  I had two more calls with GoDaddy, but still not luck.