# PHP page adding extra info from unknown source

Tags: php

I've converting my website to PHP from just static HTML.  In the process, my PHP Index file is pulling old information from an unknown source (I've deleted all my old files).

Here is the specific problem.  When I add a paragraph tag to my div id="main" section, I get "Get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career!" which isn't in my PHP file.  When I inspect in Google Chrome, this is some how appears there 

==$0  "Get the Management Certification you need to make the next step in your career! "

Does ==$0 mean something?  Where could this be coming from?

Here is the actual file:

```
<?php
    $day = date('l'); 
    $time = date('H:i');
    $hour = date('H');

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Project Management Training and Consulting">
        <meta name="keywords" content="PMP, CAPM, Agile, ITIL, PMI-ACP, SCRUM, Waldorf, MD, Washington, DC, Alexandria, VA">
        <meta name="author" content="Vince McKeown">
        <title>Jaza Solutions - Home PHP</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "jazasolutions.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <img src="jazasolutions2.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
        </div>
        <nav>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>        
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsContact.html>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsAboutUs.html>About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href=JazaSolutionsCourses.html>Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href=index.php>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <img class="imageSideRight" src="Meeting.jpeg" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
        </div>
        <div class="sideRight">
            <h2> Upcoming Classes </h2>
            <p class="microsoft marquee"><span>Enrollment discounted at 50% for a limited time for the <font color="red">6/25/18</font color> PMP boot camp.</span></p>
            <p> <font color="red">6/25/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p> 
            <p> <font color="red">7/23/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "main">
            <p> Good morning </p>

            <h1> Jaza Solutions offers industry endorsed training in: </h1>
            <ol> 
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsPMP.html>PMP</li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsCAPM.html>CAPM</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsITIL.html>ITIL</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsAgile.html>Agile & Scrum</a></li>
                <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsSixSigma.html>Six Sigma</a></li>
            </ol>
            <br>
            <h1> The Jaza Advantage: </h1>
            <ul> 
                <li> Acquire certifications in Management not just training </li>
                <li> Get trained by experts at your site or ours </li>
                <li> Flexible training hours & online training to fit your needs </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "footer">
            <img class="imageSideRight" src="PMI.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC" height="60" margin-bottom= "0px" width = "100">
            <p>  <br> Call us:  (301)861-2133 <br> Email us: info@jazasolutions.com <br><small>&copy; 2017 Jaza Solutions, LLC</small></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this happen when you test the page in other browsers? Do you have any add-ons installed in your Chrome? Also, you have no divs with the ID of "main" in the code you posted. Class yes, ID no.

Comment: I don't have any add ons.  When I tested the webpage in IE, I get the same results on the page.  I'm lost on how a <p> element automatically pulls an old <p> element I had there in the past?

Comment: Sounds weird. Tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I have.  I even called "GoDaddy," which is my webhosting 3 times on this.  Not one person can explain it.  I want to say this is a glitch somewhere on their server...

Comment: One other weird event which may have a clue.... the <p> element I've added gets replaced by what was there prior.

Comment: I tried a couple of things.  I moved that <p> element within that div and I get the same error.  If I copy and paste that <p> element to another div, I get what's actually in that <p> element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index File on GoDaddy is not displaying any PHP works perfect in local XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359057/index-file-on-godaddy-is-not-displaying-any-php-works-perfect-in-local-xampp)

Comment: I think that may be it.   I'll have to test that when I get back to my office

Comment: So I looked at all my files on GoDaddy.  I only have one index file.  Another weird thing is when I click on the "home" button, the Index page works like it's supposed to..... it's as if it's two separate files, but I know it's not???

Comment: When I delete the entire head section from the file, it works fine.  I've deleted each line individually within the head section and I couldn't get a change.  This has to be the weirdest error I've come across because I can't make sense out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why this works, but my best guess is GoDaddy is somewhere caching my old file in an unknown location.  I changed a div class from main to blank and it stopped pulling from an old file somewhere.

```
<?php
    $day = date('l'); 
    $time = date('H:i');
    $hour = date('H');

?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="description" content="Project Management Training and Consulting">
            <meta name="keywords" content="PMP, CAPM, Agile, ITIL, PMI-ACP, SCRUM, Waldorf, MD, Washington, DC, Alexandria, VA">
            <meta name="author" content="Vince McKeown">
            <title>Jaza Solutions - Home PHP</title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "jazasolutions.css" /> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "header">
                <img src="jazasolutions2.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
            </div>
            <nav>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>        
                    <li><a href=JazaSolutionsContact.html>Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href=JazaSolutionsAboutUs.html>About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href=JazaSolutionsCourses.html>Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href=index.php>Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <img class="imageSideRight" src="Meeting.jpeg" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC">
            </div>
            <div class="sideRight">
                <h2> Upcoming Classes </h2>
                <p class="microsoft marquee"><span>Enrollment discounted at 50% for a limited time for the <font color="red">6/25/18</font color> PMP boot camp.</span></p>
                <p> <font color="red">6/25/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p> 
                <p> <font color="red">7/23/18</font> PMP Bootcamp: Waldorf, MD </p>
            </div>
            <div>       
                <h1></h1>
                <h2> Jaza Solutions offers industry endorsed training in: </h2>
                <ol> 
                    <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsPMP.html>PMP</li>
                    <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsCAPM.html>CAPM</a></li>
                    <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsITIL.html>ITIL</a></li>
                    <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsAgile.html>Agile & Scrum</a></li>
                    <li> <a href=JazaSolutionsSixSigma.html>Six Sigma</a></li>
                </ol>
                <br>
                <h2> The Jaza Advantage: </h2>
                <ul> 
                    <li> Acquire certifications in Management not just training </li>
                    <li> Get trained by experts at your site or ours </li>
                    <li> Flexible training hours & online training to fit your needs </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id = "footer">
                <img class="imageSideRight" src="PMI.png" alt = "Jaza Solutions, LLC" height="60" margin-bottom= "0px" width = "100">
                <p>  <br> Call us:  (301)861-2133 <br> Email us: info@jazasolutions.com <br><small>&copy; 2017 Jaza Solutions, LLC</small></p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```